# How to get org-agenda to prefer split-window-right

Tags: org-mode, window

After upgrading to Emacs 24.4.1, when I call org-agenda with no splits it will show on the bottom half of the frame.  Previously, it would show on the right half.  How do I configure this behaviour?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this behavior is not specific to org-agenda, but rather depends on the size of the window and the variables `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold`. If your window is wide enough the agenda will open on the right.

You may want to try a lower `split-width-threshold` if you prefer to split things vertically (new window on the right). If you *really* only want to do this for org-agenda, some advice might work:

```
(defadvice org-agenda (around split-vertically activate)
  (let ((split-width-threshold 80))  ; or whatever width makes sense for you
    ad-do-it))
```

Another option is to define a command to toggle from a horizontal split to a vertical split, as described here: http://whattheemacsd.com/buffer-defuns.el-03.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  The problem seemed to be the window was large enough to split both vertically and horizontally, so it chose vertical - is there a way to get it to change which split it prefers if it can do both?

Comment: Check out the doc for `split-window-sensibly` -- I think you can set `split-height-threshold` to nil. That seems to prefer the width threshold and create windows on the right by default, but still fall back to putting the new window below if the current width is not enough.

Comment: I changed `split-width-threshold` from 160 default value to 80 on a 1920x1200 monitor. Now most things split vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the toggle-window-split function from http://whattheemacsd.com/buffer-defuns.el-03.html with advicing and it works pretty well:

See that the toggle-window-split function is available/loaded and advice like so:

```
(advice-add 'org-agenda :after #'toggle-window-split)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it might be expected it is the easily [configurable option](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specific-Customization.html). Just choose the appropriate value of

> org-agenda-window-setup

E.g.: find the current value of this variable:

> C-h v org-agenda-window-setup <Enter

Choose 'customize' and in the following menu choose the right option. Apply this change, test it up, Apply and Save it if it what you're looking for.

*Have fun!*